# Python pyinstaller and translit module

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, pyinstaller, transliteration

I'm using module *transliterate.py* from standard translit python libraries.
When I compile my GUI application, it raises the next error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\...\build\Rman\out00-PYZ.pyz\addobjectdialog", line 265, in OnTextName
  File "C:\Users\...\...\build\Rman\out00-PYZ.pyz\core.utils", line 536, in translit
  File "C:\Users\...\...\build\Rman\out00-PYZ.pyz\transliterate.utils", line 41, in translit
  File "C:\Users\...\...\build\Rman\out00-PYZ.pyz\transliterate.utils", line 29, in ensure_autodiscover
  File "C:\Users\...\...\build\Rman\out00-PYZ.pyz\transliterate.discover", line 27, in autodiscover
WindowsError: [Error 3] : 'C:\\...\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI11122\\transliterate\\contrib\\languages/*.*'
```

How I understand, I have to place
that lib somewhere within my application. But I just compile one .exe file, so wouldn't like to keep yet one file with my exe.
BTW, app is ran under Win 7 / 32bit. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That may be one of those libraries that you have to include explicitly. I know I had to do that from time to time with py2exe. See the following docs for more information:

- http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#options-for-finding-imported-modules-and-libraries